# Install software on VM that is deployed in cloud

Tags: cloud, virtualization, virtual-machine

Is it possible that after I have deployed a virtual machine (VM) into a cloud platform, to update the VM by installing new software, without to redeploy the VM?

I know that this might depend on the cloud I use, but is it possible without the need to redeploy?

Comment: Can you specify what this means: "without to redeploy the VM"?

Comment: without to need to specify to the cloud service again the configuration for the VM, just restart the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Depending on your operating system you can install whatever software you want. For example, if you're using Linux you can use apt-get or yum or if you're using Windows you can download whatever installers you need.

However, if some software requires a restart to install properly, you'll need to check and see if your cloud platform supports a VM restart.